# React Native app crashes when opened from background after unlocking the phone (Network request failed.)

Tags: ios, react-native

We have a problem with a React Native app that we're building. The app is behaving perfectly fine until the following happens:

1. the user locks the screen (*while the app is open or in the background, it doesn't matter*)
2. the user unlocks the iPhone and opens the app from a background state
3. as soon as the app makes a request to the API it crashes

---

Some notes:

- We are building the app on an actual device (both the minified and not minified bundle produce the same error).
- If the user **does not** lock the screen (only putting the app in the background), and then opens the app later on, it works perfectly fine.
- The crash happens in both the *Debug* and *Release* schemes.

We have inspected the crash both in XCode and the Chrome React Debugger and the following error happens (not that useful). (**Note:** This is using the *Debug* scheme).

```
{
    [TypeError: Network request failed]
    line: 5074,
    column: 21,
    sourceURL: 'http://192.168.0.30:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true'
}
```

The same error is produced when built with the *Release* scheme.

---

Does anybody know what could be the potential problem here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: This also appears to be happening in native apps as well. When my app becomes active it updates user details with an API request.

If the app becomes active through first opening or simply from the home screen or multitasking it works fine. If it becomes active through unlocking then the request fails with no response, no error and nothing hitting the server

Comment: @AndyRyan, I have never experienced something like that in native apps. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I asked my own question on this and it was something about The way Alamofire (pod for netwrok requests) was caching the session. Locking the phone resulted in the OS reclaiming the socket that was being used by the cached session and by creating a network request in `applicationDidBecomeActive` I was trying to use that socket before it was reopened.

The only way I could think to fix was to implement a retry on the network call. I don't know how you would do that on a non-native app

Comment: Not sure of the cause but have you tried turning on Xcode debugging? Helped me a lot with issues similar to this. Go to Product >> Scheme >> Edit Scheme, then turn on `debug executable`. After that go to the `Breakpoint Navigator` and add an exception breakpoint

Comment: Old question, but did you manage to pinpoint/solve the problem? I'm having the same issue, after coming from the background, the app does 3 API calls and only 1 of them comes through, the other two 'hang' forever